# Sending a String concatenated with variable raises an error in Minecraft

Tags: javascript, json, minecraft

Okay, so, I'm having trouble sending players strings combined with variables. For example, this line of code:

`client.write("chat", { message: ("Username:"+data.data[0]["name"].toString())})`

This `data` variable is a JSON object. Printing out

`"Username:"+data.data[0]["name"].toString()`

Works without an error, but when I try send it to the client, the client disconnects with this error message:

```
Internal Exception: io.netty.handler.codec.DecoderException: 
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: 
com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use 
JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 10
```

BTW, I'm using npm `minecraft-protocol` javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just checked the [documentation](https://github.com/PrismarineJS/node-minecraft-protocol/blob/master/docs/API.md) and the sent message doesn't correspond to the format that should be used.

The json should NOT be in json direclty, but should be stringified. So, such as the [usage](https://github.com/PrismarineJS/node-minecraft-protocol#usage) said, you should use something like that:

```
var msg = {
  translate: 'chat.type.announcement',
  "with": [
      'Username',
      data.data[0]["name"]
  ]
};
client.write("chat", { message: JSON.stringify(msg), position: 0, sender: '0' });
```

Comment: That doesn't work, data.data[0]["name"] is a String, but concatenating that with a variable and sending it to the client makes the client disconnect, your code, also does that, but with a different error message. I don't think the Message field is supposed to be a dictionary.

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't know what you should send. I just check, and edit my answer

Comment: omg, yes, tysm, but I was wondering how I could remove the brackets next to the "Username", and replace them with something more pleasant like colons?

Comment: You can't remove brackets, but you can put everything in the same line like `[ "Username", data.data[0]["name"] ]`